# "This repository is over its data quota" when cloning GitHub repo

Tags: git, github

I was cloning a github repository which has a git-lfs file.

When git-lfs client in my system tried to download the file it threw an error.

```
jeevansai@jeevansai-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ git clone https://github.com/sapgan/CS628-Assignments
Cloning into 'CS628-Assignments'...
remote: Counting objects: 21, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
remote: Total 21 (delta 1), reused 21 (delta 1), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (21/21), done.
Downloading vm-628.ova (609.62 MB)
Error downloading object: vm-628.ova (731ee03): Smudge error: Error downloading vm-628.ova (731ee0372156b90cb067a9b7fc8d3bb92c93c502ce1a7667fe045): batch response: This repository is over its data quota. Purchase more data packs to restore access.

Errors logged to /home/jeevansai/CS628-Assignments/.git/lfs/objects/logs/20170614T000317.145070866.log
Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.
error: external filter 'git-lfs filter-process' failed
fatal: vm-628.ova: smudge filter lfs failed
warning: Clone succeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what twas checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'

jeevansai@jeevansai-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ git lfs logs last
No logs to show
jeevansai@jeevansai-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ vi /home/jeevansai/CS628-Assignments/.git/lfs/objects/logs/20170614T000317.145070866.log
jeevansai@jeevansai-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$
```

Where is the problem? Is it on my system or on my Github account or the repository?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting.

Comment: Seems like the repo owner has exceeded their LFS quota and there is nothing much you can do on your own except to let the repo owner know and hope they increase their quota.

Comment: is the quota for amount of downloading or for size of file uploaded

Comment: It's clearly showing the error, please refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42464067/when-exceeding-the-data-quota-what-is-the-best-way-to-split-up-this-github-re

Comment: I understood the error but my doubt is the repository owner succesfully uploaded the file so he has enough quota required for the file and some others downloaded the file so where is the error on my side or repository side

Comment: @edwinksl that seems to be the answer

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is download the files from the github repo at github.com. https://github.com/sapgan/CS628-Assignments. Click `Clone or Download` and then `Download as ZIP`. The only difference with doing it this way, is that you have to unzip it.

Comment: Yes, I tested it and it works, unlike `git clone`!

Comment: but the download file does not contain the file stored in git-lfs it is just downloading the pointer, not the entire file,entire file size is 630MB.see the .ova file its size is around 600 bytes which is pointer original file size is large